# how to do a reduced outer product using thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a two-dimensional array, $a,$ stored in a device_vector with indices (p,i) of dimensions N and m

I want to compute

```
$$s_{ij} = \sum \limits_{p=1}^{N} a_{p,i} a_{p,j}$$

for $i,j=1,...,m.$
```

Is there an easy way to do this using thrust?

The above code is latex. In C++ it would be something like

```
Matrix A(N,m); // filled with data

Matrix S(m,m);

for (int i=0; i <m;++i)
  for (int j=0; j <m;++j) 
   { 
     S(i,j)=0;
     for (int p=0; p < N; ++p)
        S(i,j) += A(p,i)*A(p,j);

   }
```

Comment: What do you want? I cannot understand quite well looking into the symbols .

Comment: o.O   Looking at the Q, I feel like I just failed an IQ test. Could you provide serial code?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to implement outer products or Kronecker products in thrust

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this. You could do something like generate the product M X N with some fancy iterator expression and then maybe call `reduce_by_key` somehow. The performance would be unimpressive because it would not capture the reuse in the outer two nested for loops. It would be much more straightforward to adapt one of the many ad hoc N-body CUDA kernels to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I don't miss something, it seems that

```
$$s_{ij} = \sum_{p=1}^{N} a_{p,i} a_{p,j} = \sum_{p=1}^{N} a^T_{i,p} a_{p,j}$$
```

and thus

```
$$S = A^T A$$
```

the usual matrix product. I also don't think you can do this with thrust. But you can do matrix multiplication easily using CUBLAS or Arrayfire (actually i think arrayfire uses cublas internally). But keep in mind that these libraries store matrices in column-major order (like in fortran)

Comment: yes one could do it this way but my main worry is then I need two copies of the matrix. Think N very big, M quite small.